# Compute Engine fails to connect to Container Registry

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-iam

I am trying to pull my Container Registry docker image but it fails with:

```
Error response from daemon: unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your request, follow the steps in: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication
```

I am on a compute engine instance so I believe its already configured to pull? I also checked the service account and roles

[image]

I even added storage viewer role to my compute engine service account

[image]

[image]

What is wrong here?

---

Comment: In addition to permissions you need to authenticate your compute engine to connect to container registry. https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication

Comment: @MR.K you can put your comment as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to permissions you need to authenticate your compute engine to connect to container registry. Please see [Advanced Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication) for more details